# Why the total angular momentum of Helium ground state is 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Every reference I have seen says that the total angular momentum of helium ground state of is zero.

My question  is since the the Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with the total angular momentum $J$  why can we have energy eigenstate of the form $$\psi(E,J)=k(E)\phi(J)$$   such that we have
$$HK(E)=e_0k(E)$$ $$J\phi(J)=j_0\phi(J)$$
such that $e_0$ is the ground state energy and $j_0\neq0$

Comment: There are many excited states of He with $J\neq 0$.

Comment: My concern is ground state

Comment: You ask "why can we have energy eigenstate [with $j_0 \neq 0$"?

Comment: and $e_0$ is the ground state energy